Python - Cannot get expected result when having 2 twisted client
I'm using crochet to help me with the twisted architecture that the 3rd party package used. When I only have 1 instance of CTraderOpenAPI, I can get the result as expected.
However when I tried to have 2 instances one for demo and another one for live, I start getting None response
Did I miss something on my code below?
from crochet import run_in_reactor, setup
from ctrader_open_api import Auth, Client, EndPoints, Protobuf, TcpProtocol
from ctrader_open_api.messages.OpenApiMessages_pb2 import *  # noqa: F403
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

from config import config
from constant import API_TRANSACTION_SOURCE_CTRADER
from Dto.api_transaction_dto import ApiTransactionDto
from logger.log import APITransactionLogger

load_dotenv()

setup()

auth = Auth(
    config.CTRADER_CLIENT_ID, config.CTRADER_CLIENT_SECRET, config.CTRADER_REDIRECT_URL
)

timeout = 120


class CTraderOpenAPI:
    def __init__(self, host_type="demo"):
        if host_type == "demo":
            self.host_type = EndPoints.PROTOBUF_DEMO_HOST
        else:
            self.host_type = EndPoints.PROTOBUF_LIVE_HOST

        self.ctrader_client_id = config.CTRADER_CLIENT_ID
        self.ctrader_client_secret = config.CTRADER_CLIENT_SECRET
        self.redirect_uri = config.CTRADER_REDIRECT_URL

        self.init_client()

        self.authorize_app()

    def on_error(self, failure):
        print("Error: ", failure)
        print(failure.getErrorMessage())

    def disconnected(self, client, reason):
        print("\nDisconnected: ", reason)

    def encodeResult(self, result):
        if result is None:
            return

        return MessageToDict(Protobuf.extract(result))

    @run_in_reactor
    def sendProtoOAApplicationAuthReq(self):
        request = ProtoOAApplicationAuthReq()  # type: ignore # noqa: F405

        request.clientId = self.ctrader_client_id
        request.clientSecret = self.ctrader_client_secret

        deferred = self.client.send(request)
        deferred.addErrback(self.on_error)

        return deferred

    def authorize_app(self):
        d = self.sendProtoOAApplicationAuthReq()
        result = d.wait(timeout=timeout)
        encoded_result = self.encodeResult(result)
        return encoded_result

    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def init_client(self):
        self.client = Client(
            self.host_type,
            EndPoints.PROTOBUF_PORT,
            TcpProtocol,
        )
        self.client.setDisconnectedCallback(self.disconnected)
        self.client.startService()

    def stop_service(self):
        self.client.stopService()

    def get_auth_uri(self):
        return auth.getAuthUri()

    def refresh_token(self, refresh_token):
        return auth.refreshToken(refresh_token)

    def get_access_token(self, auth_code):
        token = auth.getToken(auth_code)

        if "accessToken" not in token:
            raise KeyError(token)

        return token


ctrader_client = CTraderOpenAPI()
ctrader_client_live = CTraderOpenAPI("live")


I tried to use threading, however I'm not sure I did correctly since I'm new on python
